# Integrated webcam detected but not working

Tags: drivers, 18.04, webcam

My integrated webcam was working on Ubuntu 18.04 kernel 4.18.0. Then, some problems happened and I reinstalled Ubuntu and updated it to kernel 5.3.0. After that I found my webcam not working. It shows a black screen in any camera app (e.g.: Cheese). So I searched and I tried these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install cheese build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
sudo apt-get install guvcview
```

Then, I restarted and pressed <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (the camera shortcut key) and I opened Cheese and it was working in all apps.
But in the next boot, I found it not working and it showed a black screen again. I tried the previous commands again, but nothing changed.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 058f:a014 Alcor Micro Corp. Asus Integrated Webcam
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0cf3:3005 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3011 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
$ uname -r
5.3.0-42-generic
```

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS using 18.04 or 18.04.1 media installed and used the 4.15 kernel, HWE kernels were 4.18 (18.04.2), 5.0 (18.04.3) and 5.3 (18.04.4) and 4.19 was never a Ubuntu 18.04 supported kernel (it was likely a *testing* kernel but never supported), so you were not using a Ubuntu supported kernel; or you detail is incorrect.

Comment: i'm using Ubuntu 20.04 , after a recent kernel update to 5.4.0.31 my Alcor builtin webcam also stopped working .

Answer (score 0):

Restart your system and select as the kernel any other kernel version than 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have been able to solve it by updating the kernel from version 5.4.0-33 to version 5.5.1 You can easily do it manually by following these steps:

https://www.tecmint.com/upgrade-kernel-in-ubuntu/