# Integrated webcam detected but showing no image

Tags: usb, webcam

I have a Clevo laptop with an integrated Suyin webcam (064e:3410). The webcam is detected, setting it on/off with Fn+F10 works, but there is no image showing up: the screen remains black with cheese, guvcview, v4l2 test utilities, etc.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

$ uname -a
Linux 5.8.0-050800-generic #202008022230 SMP Sun Aug 2 22:33:21 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 064e:3410 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c06c Logitech, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ cheese 
(cheese:4312): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:16:32.645: Theme parsing error: cheese.css:7:35: The style property GtkScrollbar:min-slider-length is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version

$ lsmod | grep video
uvcvideo               98304  1
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  5 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       53248  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
videodev              245760  4 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
mc                     57344  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
video                  49152  1 i915
```

[Screenshot of cheese showing black screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3o1o.png)

I have found these two similar posts, among many others after googling many hours, but no solution so far: [Integrated webcam detected but not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1220869/integrated-webcam-detected-but-not-working) and
[Webcam detected but not showing up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179730/webcam-detected-but-not-showing-up)

Furthermore, the webcam is reported to work with Debian 10, but I have tried it from a fresh and clean live system (USB stick) and I get the same result: https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=usb:064e-3410

Any hint will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If it works with

```
vlc v4l2:///dev/video0
```

then you could use OBS Studio to load the VLC `v4l2:///dev/video0` and start the  virtual webcam.
I had this problem with an ancient Logitech webcam and this was the way I solved the problem.